# Can a macOS application change its own environment variables?

Tags: xcode, macos

I know you can set the environment for a sub-process using NSTask on launch, but is it possible for a running application to change its own environment? If so, how?

Comment: Using `setenv` ([setenv](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/setenv.3.html))

Comment: I verified and setenv works from Swift as well, so this is a great answer. You should respond as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `setenv`

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/setenv.3.html):

> The setenv() function inserts or resets the environment variable name in
>        the current environment list.

An example in C would look like:

```
setenv("MY_VARIABLE", "my value", 1)
```

And should also work from swift.